# Autenticação com 3 parâmetros Json Web Token (JWT)?

Tags: php, json, laravel, jwt

Eu estou fazendo um sistema de login com Laravel utilizando JWT, todavia eu preciso passar 3 parâmetros, sendo eles um identificador, usuario e senha. Eu consigo pegar esses parâmetros mas não consigo autenticar com o banco. Ele faz a verificação do usuário e da senha, mas desse primeiro parâmetro (o identificador, que é necessário para montar o menu) ele não faz a verificação.
Alguém já utilizou JWT passando 3 parâmetros? Como posso fazer a verificação desses 3 parâmetros?

Estou utilizando https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth . Segue abaixo trecho do meu código:

```
public function authenticateJson(Request $request) {
    // pega as credenciais para o login
    $credentials = $request->only('login', 'password');
    $customClaims = ['ep_chave' => $request->only('ep_chave')];
    try {
        // verifica o login e cria o token
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, $customClaims)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Login ou senha inválidos'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        //Erro para Criar o token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Não foi possível criar o token'], 500);
    }

    // Caso tudo ok retorna o token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

Comment: Ele cria o Token?

Comment: Sim, cria o token. Se eu tirar o campo ep_chave, inclusive faz o login normal, porém não verifica se o ep_chave corresponde com o que tem no banco.

Comment: Entendi, se tem que verificar de outra forma Alberto

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o problema, segue abaixo o código que funcionou para mim.
Agradeço a todos que se prontificaram a ajudar.

```
public function authenticateJson(Request $request) {
    // pega as credenciais para o login
    $credentials = $request->only('login', 'password', 'ep_chave');

    // faz a validação dos campos recebidos
    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
        'ep_chave' => 'required',
        'login' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    // se o campo não for plenamente validado retorna a mensagem de erro
    if ( $validator->fails() ) {  
        return response()->json($validator->errors()->getMessages(), 400);
    }

    try {
        // verifica o login e cria o token
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Login ou senha inválidos'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        //Erro para Criar o token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Não foi possível criar o token'], 500);
    }

    // Caso tudo ok retorna o token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

Comment: Você apenas adicionou um validator, isso faz com que o campo `ep_chave` seja required mas não garante que é o mesmo que está no banco. Se você testar um usuário com login e senha correto e o `ep_chave` errado, ele vai gerar o token do mesmo jeito.